# LoadLibrary из DllMain

Tags: winapi

Здравствуйте. Мне именно внутри DllMain очень нужно вызвать LoadLibrary(X) и использовать её(X) функции.
Чем это грозит, если:
 1. библиотека X использует (импортирует) ТОЛЬКО функции Kernel32.dll. Соответственно ее загрузка не может существенно повлиять на порядок загрузки DLLs процесса и не может привести к dependency loops при загрузке DLLs, так ведь?
 2. при инициализации библиотеки X и внутри экспортируемых ей функций НЕ создаются новые потоки и НЕ используются примитивы синхронизации, НЕ вызывается LoadLibrary?

Comment: Зовите GetModuleHandle (модуль ведь уже загружен, второй раз его можно и не грузить). Странно, возможно не правильно зовёте.

Comment: Нельзя звать LoadLibrary в DllMain: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684596/8766

Comment: mega, я читал MSDN. Там написано "вы не должны звать LoadLibrary в DllMain" и далее написано почему. Если бы было нельзя, то LoadLibrary  из DllMain возвращал бы 0 или  генерировал бы исключение.

Comment: Но вызов выполняетя успешно. Инициализация  проходит. Вообще у меня все работает. Дедлоков, крашей не происходит. Я спрашиваю чем грозит именно при выполнении всех переисленных условий.

Comment: А, ну если все работает... Меня первый комментарий сбил с толку. На самом деле, Вам просто повезло. Любой лишний вызов, который можете добавить не только Вы, но и любой последующий апдейт винды - и получите дедлок.

Comment: @Александр: Вы не вполне понимаете значение слова «нельзя». «Нельзя» — это не значит «не делайте так, или получите линейкой по пальцам». Языки наподобие C, а также WinAPI считают вас взрослым, и не контролируют выполнение запретов. Просто нормальная работа программы в этом случае не гарантирована. Может сработать, может не сработать, как повезёт.

Comment: То, что работает сейчас, не обязано работать в будущем. Достаточно в одном из патчей слегка изменить загрузчик исполняемых файлов — и на ровном месте возникнет взаимоблокировка.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо вопрос переусложнен условиями, важность которых не всем ясна. Сделаю условия проще: Чем грозит LoadLibrary(X) из DllMain, если X - пустая библиотека с одной единственной функцией DllMain которая ничего не делает и просто возвращает TRUE. Loader lock - это критическая секция, она реентерабельна для одного потока, поэтому каких-то дедлоков в таком случае просто не может быть. Так же при таком варианте не может быть никаких вызовов функций еще не инициализированных библиотек, потому что X - пустая. Может ли явная загрузка dll через LoadLibrary из DllMain сама по себе повредить какие-то данные в процессе (ведь только в таком случае возможны краши, которыми пугают в MSDN)?